# Is there anyone know where Firefox add-ons or extensions are in the memory? How can I find them in memory

Tags: firefox, memory, memory-management

I am running Firefox with version 10.0.2 on Linux (CentOS). From the memory descriptor (mm_struct) of Firefox, I know the location of Firefox code section. The code of Firefox add-ons or extensions have to be stored somewhere in memory too, and the Firefox application itself must be aware of these code. Does anyone know where Firefox add-ons or extensions are in memory? Are they associated with the code section of Firefox? How can I find them? Thanks for any inputs.

Answer (score 1):

Extensions are written in JavaScript, so their code would just be on the heap.

Comment: Thank you. Do you know how to find them in memory?

Comment: Another questions is: Most system has NX protection techniques, and how can extensions be executed in the heap? Thanks!

Comment: You'd have to work internal data structures to find things in memory.  As for NX, there is no barrier to interpreting things with NX.  For a JIT, one would flip the NX bit before generating the jitcode and marking it executable...

Comment: Sorry to keep bothering you. I used the memory descriptor (mm_struct) of Firefox and found out the heap location. Next, I want to find out the extension code in heap. Am I supposed to look at the source code of Firefox? I downloaded the source code, it seems like a very big file and I am not familiar with the Firefox source code. Could you please give me some directions where I can find these internal data structures? 
Many Thanks!

Comment: I have no idea how to get there from the C heap.  The exact place where these things will live in memory completely depends on what the allocator does at runtime.  I do suggest looking up how interpreted code works, though.... the "extension code" on the heap is not machine code.